# For what c is the Banach fixed-point theorem true?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

We have $g(x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{6} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1x_2+cx_2-1\\
x_1^2-x_2+1
\end{pmatrix}$

For what $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is the condition of the Banach fixed-point theorem in set $M = [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ fulfilled?

My attempt was to do $||g(x_1,x_2)-g(y_1,y_2)||_\infty$ but I could not make it to the statement $k||x-y||_\infty$

Comment: The Banach fixed point theorem is true for any $c$.

Comment: It would improve the Question to ask explicitly about the condition involving  $c$ (rather than merely mention the Banach fixed point theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Let us fix $x=(x_1,x_2)$, and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ in $M$.
So we can use in estimations $|x_1|, |x_2|; |y_1|, |y_2|, \le 1$.

Let $a$ be the supremum norm of $x-y$, so $|x_1-y_1|\le a$ and $
|x_2-y_2|\le a$.

Then we have using brute force:
$$
\begin{aligned}
|(g(x)-g(y))_1|
&=\frac 16|\ x_1x_2+cx_2-y_1y_2-cy_2\ |
\\
&\le 
\frac 16|\ x_1x_2-y_1y_2\ |
+
\frac {|c|}6|x_2-y_2|
\\
&= 
\frac 16|\ x_1x_2-x_1y_2+x_1y_2-y_1y_2\ |
+
\frac {|c|}6a
\\
&\le 
\frac 16|x_1|\cdot |x_2-y_2|
+
\frac 16|y_2|\cdot |x_1-y_1|
+
\frac {|c|}6a
\\
&=
\left(
\frac 16|x_1|
+
\frac 16|y_2|
+
\frac {|c|}6
\right)a
\\
&\le
\left(
\frac 16+
\frac 16+
\frac {|c|}6
\right)a\ ,
\\[3mm]
|(g(x)-g(y))_2|
&=\frac 16|\ x_1^2-x_2-y_1^2+y_2\ |
\\
&\le 
\frac 16|x_1+y_1|\cdot|x_1-y_1|+\frac 16|x_2-y_2|
\\
&\le
\left(\frac 16\cdot 2+\frac 16\right)a=\frac 12 a
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
From this,
$$
\|\ g(x)-g(y)\ \|_\infty
\le 
\max\left(\ \frac {2+|c|}6,\ \frac 12\ \right)\|x-y\|_\infty\ .
$$
For $c\in(-4,4)$ we have thus a contraction. (The problem considers only $c>0$, but we have not used it.)

Do we need to find **all** $c$, so that we have a contraction?